# Data not shown in slickgrid

Tags: javascript, html, slickgrid

I'm working with slickgrid in my webpage, the problem I'm getting while using it that I'm unable to see the data in the grid. While when I try to get the data through grid object (i.e. grid.getData();) , I can get the whole data which I have previously set in the grid but don't know why its not showing up. May be I'm missing some thing.

following is my code for drawing the grid.

HTML code:

```
<div id="myGrid" width="100%"; height="500px"></div>
```

JS code:

```
drawBlotterForOrders : function(data){
    try{
        var columns = this.getBlotterColumns();
        var options = {
             enableCellNavigation: true,
            enableColumnReorder: false
        };

        var dataArray = [];
        dataArray = self.setDataInGrid(data);
        gridObj = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid" , dataArray , columns , options);
        console.log(gridObj.getData());//here I'm able to get the data
    }catch(exp){
    }
},

setDataInGrid : function(data){
    try{
        var dataArray = [];
        i++;
        dataArray[0] = {
            id : i,
            clOrdId : data.clOrdId,
            cumQty : data.cumQty,
            execId : data.execId,
            execType : data.execType,
            leavesQty : data.leavesQty,
            ordStatus : data.ordStatus,
            orderId : data.orderId,
            orderQty : data.orderQty,
            side : data.side,
            symbol : data.symbol
        };
        return dataArray;
    }catch(exp){
    }
},

getBlotterColumns : function(){
    var col = [
            {   id: 'id',
                name : 'id',
                field : 'id' 
            },{ 
                id: 'clOrdId',
                name : 'clOrdId',
                field : 'clOrdId' 
            },{
                id: 'cumQty',
                name : 'cumQty',
                field : 'cumQty'
            },{
                id: 'execId',
                name : 'execId',
                field : 'execId'
            },{
                id: 'execType',
                name : 'execType', 
                field : 'execType'
            },{
                id: 'leavesQty',
                name : 'leavesQty',
                field : 'leavesQty' 
            },{
                id: 'ordStatus',
                name : 'ordStatus',
                field : 'ordStatus'
            },{
                id: 'orderId',
                name : 'orderId',
                field : 'orderId'
            },{
                id: 'orderQty',
                name : 'orderQty',
                field : 'orderQty'
            },{
                id: 'side',
                name : 'side' ,
                field : 'side'
            },{
                id: 'symbol',
                name : 'symbol',
                field : 'symbol'
            }
        ];
    return col;
}
```

I'm unable to detect the mistake I'm making. I'll be really thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to render the grid I think, did you put a `grid.render()` ?